# Sharepoint Item rest query How to get the multiline column value which has append text property set true

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnpjs

I have a multiline column named as "Notes" in a list. This column has the "append text" property set to true.
So when I retrieve the item I am getting this column null value. Please help me query this.

```
  let web : Web = new Web("<Site URL>");
  let list = web.lists.getByTitle("<List Title>");
  let listItem = list.items.getById(1).select("Title", "Notes");
  listItem.get();
```

I am using pnpjs I tried directly querying using rest that is also not helping. PNPJS internally calling rest api only.

Comment: Try your endpoint in browser like this `siteUrl_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/Items?$select=Title,Notes` and check if it working or not.

Answer (score 1):

The "append text" option means that the older entries are stored in the version history. It's odd that you're reporting that the current item is empty, as it should have the last value. Perhaps the item was edited and nothing was entered for the notes field? In that case, the current value would indeed be empty, and the older values would be in the version history. To get the older values from your notes field, try the following rest call:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items(1)/versions?$select=Created,Title,Notes
```